# Что тут не так? почему ругается компилятор на параметры?

Tags: java

Есть задание:

> Вам надо написать метод имеющий три целочисленных параметра и возвращающий
> максимальное из них.

но компилятор ругается на параметры, почему?
что я сделал:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class HW1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        public static int maxInt(int a, int  b, int c){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
            a = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
            b = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
            c = sc.nextInt();

            int[] array = new int[3];
            array[0] = a;
            array[1] = a;
            array[2] = c;

            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.println("max value is " + array[2] );


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **возвращающий** *(`return`), a не печатающий; ни Scanner, ни println не нужны;

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster так из запроса видно в чем проблема... И как бы иначе автор запроса разъяснил свою проблему?

Comment: @BigTows цель StackOverflow собрать базу знаний по прикладным вопросам, а не чужие домашки доделывать. Перечитайте сообщение выше - только в таком виде подобный вопрос мог бы быть хоть сколько-нибудь полезным (данный вопрос - нет, т.к. в сообщении об ошибке уже будет сказано что не так и исправление тривиально)

Comment: @Kromster Возможно у меня сложилось ложное впечатление о StackOverflow, но  для меня это "Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов." . Идея сбора "золотой коллекции" хороша, но почему бы при этом не помочь новичкам, а когда вопрос на ответ будет получен, просто скрыть данный вопрос, если он как вы говорите прост. (Я не говорю про вопросы типа: "Вот у меня есть текст, а надо сделать код, как?")

Comment: @BigTows вот через "сайт вопросов и ответов" и получается отбор в "коллекцию". Беда данного вопроса в том, что он по сути "вот мое задание, вот я что-то сделал, оно ругается, догадайтесь что не так или переделайте за меня".

Comment: я тоже новичок. мне вот здесь непонятно. зачем это было писать ? ```
int[] array = new int[3]; array[0] = a; array[1] = a; array[2] = c;
```

Comment: чтоб отсортировать потом

Comment: у вас 0 и 1 равняется a ?

Comment: ну, там сплошной бред

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У вас объявлен метод в методе, если вы хотите сделать метод, который определяет Max int, необходимо объявить его отдельно.
2. У вас в сигнатуре метода `maxInt` есть переменные, хотя вы их не используете (вы задаете их посредствам ввода с клавиатуры)
3. Ваш метод `maxInt` объявлен как метод который возвращает значение `int` (число), хотя по факту ничего не возвращает.